# how to scan scope data and find custom data in JS?

Tags: javascript, date, scope

i don't know how solve my javascript date problem.
I have form, and i get two date from input. This date create scope, and i need scan  this scope and if i find date which is event i need count it.

In every years events are in other time, so i should create 20 arrays for 20 years?
How i can scan date scope?

```
<input type="date" id="dateTerm" min="2000-12-31" required="required">
<input type="date" id="datePay" min="2000-12-31" required="required">

 const dateTerm = document.querySelector('#dateTerm'); 
 const datePay= document.querySelector('#datePay');
```

Comment: You seem to be asking a number of questions here: how to get the value of an input, how to convert it to a date, how to use two dates to find if other dates are in a range. Maybe others. Please address one at a time. All of these questions have been answered here before.

Comment: ok, you've right i should improve my looking skill :D

Comment: I have no idea what kind of "scope" you are referring to.